# Gmail keyboard shortcut for navigating tab groupings

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

The keyboard shortcuts do not work properly for me. I am only able to cycle right to left using ~ (which requires holding shift and pressing ` . However, just pressing does not cycle left to right as it should. Anyone else having this problem? I've tested it in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari and on Windows 8.1 and OS X 10.8.5. I've also tested it in a clean browser with no plugins or extensions to interfere. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: What are 'tab groupings'?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal I assume these are the "inbox" tabs: Primary, Social, Promotions, Updates and Forums (some, all or none of these might be enabled - I personally only use the "Primary" tab, so I don't see any.)

Answer (score -1):

Be sure that in your Gmail account settings, the option *Keyboard shortcuts* is **On**.

Comment: If "Keyboard shortcuts" was "off" then presumably the OP wouldn't be able to "cycle right to left using `~`"?